# why a new datalab VM has already all the files on Master branch?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

When I created new Datalab VM on GCP, i see that the new VM which is assigned to a specific user has already all the files of Master Branch on his notebooks.
In this case the user can see all the files which he might not need at all and he has not pushed on the repository.
Is there any configuration that users can see only the files they have pushed on the repository without see the files of others?

Comment: Git doesn't work this way.  In general, Git is a repository based VCS, and a given branch contains _all_ the files in the project.

Comment: If you're using a vanilla Datalab image, it should have cloned the official doc files from github.com/googledatalab/notebooks. Users can then create their own notebooks under `/content` so they're persisted between VM restarts.